# getServletContext().getResource(file3) returns null url resource

Tags: servlets, resources

Here is my code which reads excelsheet files.but i can see my other functions are working fine but when try to get resource as url it return null.

```
    URL resource = null;
    try {
        System.out.println(file3);
        resource = getServletContext().getResource(file3);
        System.out.println("Problem with getting resource"+resource);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    File file = null;
    try {
        System.out.println(resource.toURI());
        file = new File(resource.toURI());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    FileInputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        Workbook w;
        w = Workbook.getWorkbook(input);
          // Get the first sheet
        Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);

     return sheet;
```

Comment: Where these excel files reside - inside your application or outside

Comment: What is the value of `file3`?

Comment: its  "/sheets/businesshrs6.xls" And this files are in war folder unders sheets folder

Comment: what product are you using?

Comment: Side note: Any particular reason you're using `getResource` instead of `getResourceAsStream`?

Comment: I deleted my previous answer - sorry made a mistake. The product is WebSphere Liberty it is getRealPath that returns null and not getResource when and application is a zipped war file.